# What is the purpose of active executable in xcode project?

Tags: xcode

Just want to know what is the purpose of active executable in xcode project?

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 15, accepted):

found it myself .. hope it will help someone.

Executable environments in which you can run and test a software product. An executable environment defines the program that should be used to run the product with. In many cases, this will be the product itself, but doesn't have to be. In addition, the executable environment defines any command-line arguments and environment variables which should be used.
[image]

When you execute the Build and Run command (Command-R), Xcode processes a target that performs a set of actions on source code that in turn produces a product. Then, Xcode runs the product using the active executable environment.

"But wait," you might ask, "why does an executable environment have to be set up? Can't you just run the product directly?" That's a good question. If it were just a matter of running a built Cocoa application, then defining an executable environment would be overkill. However, there are many products, such as plug-ins, that require you to define a host application in which to run the product. Executable environments are also used to run products in the debugger. You can even define multiple executable environments to run the same product in different ways.

refer to this page for more info - 
http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodeprojects.html

Comment: Nice explanation..you have +1 for it.